# Unable to load data using JSONP store in Sencha Architect

Tags: node.js, extjs, jsonp, mean-stack, sencha-architect

I am using JSONP store in Sencha Architect to load data in a store from a different domain. While loading i am getting the error: 
**Unable to load data using the supplied configuration.
Open in Browser: 
http://103.231.40.150:2525/pooltoopanel/dashboard/secure/engagement?tm=0**

The Url i am trying to hit for getting the response is **http://103.231.40.150:2525/pooltoopanel/dashboard/secure/engagement?tm=0**

[image: Screenshot of project code in Sencha Architect]

I also tried another thing. I copied the JSON response in a file and saved it inside my sencha workspace directory (ride/top.json). I wrapped the response with callback function and also changed the Proxy url to ride/top.json. Still getting the same response. Can anyone suggest what am i missing??.

Comment: will be  something from crossdomain?

Comment: enable cross domain requests with a chrome plugin and it will work

Comment: Suggest you read the docs for JSONP.

Comment: I have created a test api in Nodejs (MEAN STACK) app http://localhost:3000/admin/getchurch. I am hitting this api from architect with callback key. I am reading this key value on server side and then sending the Json returned wrapped inside callback key value. Still the issue. The url getting hit is like **GET /admin/getchurch?_dc=1509006864064&page=1&start=0&limit=25&callback=Ext.data.JsonP.callback10.** @Mr.Bruno

Comment: Did this using express JSONP response in api. Default is callback. If key is different then need to set using app.set method. Thanks.